# Finding the customers who did not order all 3 types of pizzas

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

```
customers:
+-----------+-----------+
| cid       | name      |
+-----------+-----------+
| 1         | a         | 
| 2         | b         |
| 3         | c         |
+-----------+-----------+

pizza:
+-----------+-----------+
| pid       | type      |
+-----------+-----------+
| 1         | sausage   |
| 2         | cheese    |
| 3         | veggies   |
| 4         | sausage   |
| 5         | veggies   |
| 6         | sausage   |
| 7         | sausage   |
+-----------+-----------+

orders:
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| oid       | cid       | pid       |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1         | 1         | 1         | 
| 2         | 1         | 2         |
| 3         | 2         | 3         |
| 4         | 3         | 4         |
| 5         | 1         | 5         |
| 6         | 3         | 6         |
| 7         | 3         | 7         |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around sql logic. How do I find the customers who did not order all 3 types of pizza? The three types are sausage, cheese and veggies. Do I need to use `NOT EXIST`?

Comment: Why are there duplicates in the pizza table? Do you have control over this dataset or was it given to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `having` clause to look for customers that have ordered less than 3 pizza types:

```
select  c.name
from    customers c
join    orders c
on      c.cid = c.id
join    pizza p
on      p.id = c.pid
group by
        c.name
having
        count(distinct p.type) < 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
select c.cid,
  c.name
from customers c
left join orders o
  on c.cid = o.cid
left join pizza p
  on o.pid = p.pid
where p."type" in ('sausage', 'cheese', 'veggies')  -- if you have more pizza types list them here
group by c.cid, c.name
having count(distinct "type") <> (select count(distinct "type")
                                  from pizza)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d365a/9)

Or

```
select c.cid,
  c.name
from customers c
left join orders o
  on c.cid = o.cid
left join pizza p
  on o.pid = p.pid
where p."type" in ('sausage', 'cheese', 'veggies')
group by c.cid, c.name
having count(distinct "type") <> 3  -- this is equal to the number of pizza types from the IN clause above
```

Answer (score 0):

`select cid, count(distinct type) as c from orders join pizza on orders.pid = pizza.pid  group by cid having c < 3;`